# Angular *ngFor "id" tag generation incorrect with `mat-button-toggle`

Tags: javascript, angular, ngfor

I'm trying to generate a list of buttons from an array:

```
<div class="card-container">
    <mat-button-toggle *ngFor="let button of buttonsFromApi" id={{button.id}} class="problemButton" [disabled]="sso.invalid" >{{button.id}}</mat-button-toggle>
</div>
```

`buttonsFromApi` contains 5 objects like:

```
{
    displayName: "Button name", 
    id: "100",
}
```

So basically I want the button to display the `displayName` (this works) and to have the id that is in the object. The latter of this does not happen, but instead, the button(s) have id(s) like `100-button` and `200-button` instead of `100` and `200`. Why is this and how can I make it so the ids are `100` and `200`  instead of `100-button` and `200-button`?

Comment: Maybe it _is_ the value of the `id` property. If you put `<pre>{{ button | json }}</pre>` inside the loop - what would you see?

Comment: I don't know how to do this - do you mean `<mat-button-toggle *ngFor="let button of buttonsFromApi" <pre>{{ button | json }}</pre> [attr.id]="button.id" >{{button.displayName}}</mat-button-toggle>` ?
`

Comment: As another element. Paste it next to the `<mat-button-toggle>`, for example. Or even instead of it.

Comment: You must be appending `-button` somewhere in your application.

Comment: I am not but `mat-button-toggle` might...

Comment: If you add `{{button.id}}` in your html, what do you see? `mat-button-toggle` does not append anything to the `id`. Either way, you're `id` is on the `div` not on `mat-button-toggle`

Comment: `100` and `200` as expected. I think `mat-button-toggle` adds the button part somehow...

Comment: @nash11 I'm sorry this is not my code just the default example from Angular's documentation.

Comment: @lte__ That's how it's designed [get ButtonId()](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/button-toggle/button-toggle.ts#L425) and [id=buttonId](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/button-toggle/button-toggle.html#L3)

Comment: @barbsan oh dang, so no way to change it without messing with the source code?

Comment: @nash11 That's not my code, you're generating multiple divs with buttons inside each, and the divs have the id. I have one div that I generate buttons into, and the buttons should have the ID, not the enclosing div (I don't want an enclosing div for each button)

Comment: @lte__ I think so. But if you rely on id attributes, maybe there is some different way to solve your issue (so that you could stop relying on it).

Comment: @lte__ - My bad, I had blatantly misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to override (or better extend) the default-button-id from angular material, you have to pass in the id. (https://material.angular.io/components/button-toggle/api#MatButtonToggle)

```
<div>
  <mat-button-toggle id="test-123" value="right" aria-label="Text align right"></mat-button-toggle>
</div>
```

the you will get your id inside the component:

```html
<mat-button-toggle ... id="test-123">
  <button class="mat-button-toggle-button" type="button" id="test-123-button" tabindex="0" aria-pressed="false" aria-label="Text align right">
<div class="mat-button-toggle-label-content"></div>
</button>
...
</mat-button-toggle>
```

Comment: Yes this is what I'm doing but i *don't* want the component to have `100-button`, just `100`. I don't know how your answer fixes this issue.

Comment: @lte__ what's the component for you? the <mat-button-toggle> or the <div>+<mat-button-toggle> ?

Answer (score 1):

Id should be assigned in quotes

```
<div *ngFor="let button of buttonsFromApi" id="{{button.id}}">
  <mat-button-toggle>{{button.displayName}}</mat-button-toggle>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't fix the issue - it's still generated as `100-button` etc.

Comment: Whats the output of id inside toggle `<mat-button-toggle>{{button.id}}</mat-button-toggle>`

Comment: That does work fine, it outputs as `100` `200` etc. However if I assign it to the id, it adds `-button`.

Answer (score 0):

Use attribute binding with square brackets:

```
<div *ngFor="let button of buttonsFromApi" [attr.id]="button.id">
```

Comment: This results in the buttons getting IDs like `id="mat-button-toggle-0-button"`